I want categories to direct directly to their product if they only have one product. Is there any way to do this?
I have some categories that include multiple products and some that only have one. What I want to do, is when a customer clicks on a category that only has one product, is to redirect him directly to the product, and not to the category. Is there any way to do this?
I couldn't find anything about this in the woocommerce settings, categories settings or products settings.

Okay I managed to solve this, I added this php code:
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_specific_parent_cat'); 
function redirect_specific_parent_cat() { 
    if (is_product_category()) { 
        $cat = get_queried_object(); 
        $parent_cat_id = $cat->parent; 
        $specific_parent_id = 33; 
        // Check if the current category's parent is the specific parent category 
        if ($parent_cat_id <> $specific_parent_id) { 
            $products = new WP_Query(array( 
                'post_type' => 'product', 
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                'fields' => 'ids', 
                'tax_query' => array( array( 
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
                    'field' => 'term_id', 
                    'terms' => $cat->term_id, 
                    ), 
                    ), 
                    )); 
        // Check products in the current category 
        if ($products->post_count == 1) { 
            $product_id = reset($products->posts); 
            wp_redirect(get_permalink($product_id)); 
            exit; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
